# Code-hovering outer html element when user makes "mouseon" on inner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

CSS code:

```
div.albumTitleBackground {
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1;
        background-color:whitesmoke;
        /*top:2.5%;
        left:2.5%;
        right:2.5%;
        bottom:2.5%;*/
        top:0;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        opacity:0;
        transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    }

    div.albumTitleText {
        display:inline-block;
        font-family:'Times New Roman';
        font-size:6em;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:2;
        color:darkgray;
        top:50%;
        left:5%;
    }`
```

HTML code:

`<div class="albumTitleBackground"></div>
<div class="albumTitleText">
@albumPreviewPhoto.ParentAlbumTitle
</div>`

Problem: the idea is that background of the 'albumTitleBackground' div should be animated when user enters inside the element **and must remain the same when user hovers the 'albumTitleText' div**. Which way is the easiest one (and cross-browser as like) to achive that?

Comment: You're animating this with CSS right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to do this:

Two involve changing your HTML

1) As @melwynpawar says, you need to wrap your title div inside your background div.

```
<div class="albumTitleBackground">
    <div class="albumTitleText">
        @albumPreviewPhoto.ParentAlbumTitle
    </div>
</div>
```

And use CSS:

```
.albumTitleBackground:hover {
/* Animations Here */
}
```

2) You could wrap it all in a container div. Like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="albumTitleBackground"></div>
    <div class="albumTitleText">
        @albumPreviewPhoto.ParentAlbumTitle
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.container:hover .albumTitleBackground {
/* Animations Here */
}
```

And then without changing your HTML

3) Two CSS rules

```
<div class="albumTitleBackground"></div>
<div class="albumTitleText">
    @albumPreviewPhoto.ParentAlbumTitle
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.albumTitleBackground:hover {
/* Animations Here */
}
.albumTitleText:hover .albumTitleBackground {
/* Animations Here */
}
```

This last one is not recommend because you will have to consistently check that the two rules are the same. Note that the animation will probably restart when you move from one div to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML structure to

```
<div class="albumTitleBackground">
    <div class="albumTitleText">
       @albumPreviewPhoto.ParentAlbumTitle
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to wrap the title text inside the Title background div